# Blank page then using Print()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to open an new window and print the content. I have found a way to open and display the content correct:[image]

But then i hit the print button it looks like this:[image]

And the code for showing the new window look like this. I want it to automatically show the print dialog then the window opens, but i have tried with an delay, still the same result.

```
 function PrintHistory() {
        var content = $("#InProcessPanelTbl").clone();
        content.append("<button onclick=\"window.print();\">Print</button>");
        content.css("margin-left", "30px");
         var printWindow = window.open("","_blank","status=0,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=1"),
            html = $("html").clone(),
            printElement = content, body;

         printWindow.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body></body></html>");

      $(printWindow.document).find("html")
                            .replaceWith(html);
      body = $(printWindow.document).find("body").html(printElement);

      delay(function () {
          printWindow.print();
      }, 1000);

    };
```

Comment: its working fine in my system. can you give a fiddle replicating the problem.

Comment: Fiddle or your html and css in the question will help

Comment: I have tried. But Fiddle dont allow document.write so it's hard to do.